# what is actual value and expected value in attribute grammar?

Tags: attributes, grammar, semantics

I'm studying attribute grammar, and when I talk about the semantic rule of each syntax rule, the words actual value and expected value come up. But I don't know in what situation to use actual or expected.
For example, when there is a creation rule like

```
<assign> → <id> = <expr>
<id> → A|B|C
<expr> → <id> + <expr> | <id> * <expr> |( <expr>)| <id>
```

> syntax rule: <assign> → <id> = <expr>
>
> semantic rule: <expr>.expected_type ← <id>.actual_type

> syntax rule: <expr> → <id>
>
> semantic rule: <expr>.actual_type ← <id>.actual_type

At first, I thought it was actual_value if it was on the left side of the production rule, and expected_value if it was on the right side, but it was confirmed that this is different for each production rule. What exactly are actual_value and expected_value and when to use each

Answer (score 0, accepted):

They are just names.

When you write an attribute grammar, you need to give the attributes names, just like when you write a program, you need to give your variables names.

So whoever wrote that grammar thought that those particular identifiers would make sense to whoever was reading the code.

In fact, that is rarely the case, which is why it's important to comment your code. Whoever wrote that grammar should have done that.

Anyway, we can guess what they meant (although I'm not convinced that it's the best solution). The `actual_type` of an expression is presumably the type of the value produced by that expression. So if the expression is an `id`, the type of the expression is precisely the declared type of the variable that `id` represents. (More interesting would be to see how they set the actual type of an expression which requires conversions, like `2 + 3.5`.)

If variables have declared types, then an assignment to a variable might involve a conversion. (For example, if `x` has a floating point type and `i` has an integer type, `x = i + 2` requires the compiler to issue an instruction which changes the integer value computed from `i+2` into a floating point value.) Whoever wrote that attribute grammar thought it would make sense to record the required conversion as the `expected_type` of the expression; in other words, the type of the value which the assignment needs.